# Can't get Spark to use more than a few percent resources on AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I've been trying to run a Spark job over AWS EMR and YARN in cluster mode, and no combination of settings lead to the job using at most a few percent of the total resources available.

```
val queries =  spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("input_file.csv")
  .rdd

val result = queries.map(q => doSomethingWith(q))
```

Here is the typical CPU usage chart for all nodes (master node is the one starting with 20% and then going down, the others are all slave nodes):

[image]

The above chart was obtained with the following nodes:

```
Master: 1x r4.2xlarge (8 cores,  61GB RAM)
Slaves: 4x r4.8xlarge (32 cores, 244GB RAM)
```

Running with the following settings:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class Run --master yarn s3://app.jar

Classification      Property                                Value
spark               maximizeResourceAllocation              true
spark-defaults      spark.executor.cores                    10
spark-defaults      spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled         true
spark-defaults      spark.executor.instances                12
spark-defaults      spark.executor.memory                   76g
yarn-site           yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb     245760
yarn-site           yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores    30
```

I've tried to follow all typical recommendations, including the ones in [Spark's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html), on [AWS EMR documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html?shortFooter=true) and the ones from [this article on Cloudera's blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/).

All these articles are pretty unanimous in stating that Spark is bad at automatically using resources, and they state that you have to tell him (and YARN) how much resources it must use instead.

My experience so far is that whatever the parameters and values are, Spark/Yarn don't care and the CPU usage chart is **always** the same (similar to the one pictured above).

Comment: What makes you think that utilization should be higher for a specific data?

Comment: @user8371915 not sure to understand your question correctly, but the same job, with the same data, running locally as a regular Scala parallel collection (no Spark) takes 100% CPU power and runs 20x faster.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you are being limited in how well the work can be partitioned: if the files (.gz?) or data cannot be split up, you don't get any parallelism.

If you turn inferSchema on then Spark will read through the entire file once just to work out what the schema is, then go back and reread it; this is (literally) expensive on S3. The spark master will do that end-to-end before scheduling any work.

One thing to try: make that initial job a simple ETL: `load().write().partitionBy("date").format("parquet).save(hdfs://)` and then use that set of partitioned files for the future work. Multiple files -> multiple workers, even if the file format itself can't be split up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Data is straightforward .csv file, with one item per row, no connection between rows. Only element of interest perhaps, is that the .csv file is read directly over Amazon s3 and does not come from the disk, but I doubt it has an effect.

Comment: I just edited the question and mentioned how the data is obtained.